# .NET Application Updater Component without Webdav

Tags: c#, webdav

Does the .NET Application Updater Component (http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx) work without the WebDav protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the page you linked:

*The .NET Application Updater component uses HTTP-DAV to download the application update and **thus requires a Web server that supports HTTP-DAV**.*

Although the source code is supplied, so you could possibly modify it to work another way.